# config.action_controller.asset_path_template -- undefined method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use:

https://github.com/polleverywhere/asset_fingerprinter

To install for Rails 3 you need to set:

```
config.action_controller.asset_path_template = AssetFingerprinter.path_rewriter
```

But that errors with:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@andyw/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:54:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>': undefined method `asset_path_template=' for ActionController::Base:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is this you? If so did it resolve the issue? If not does it help? https://github.com/polleverywhere/asset_fingerprinter/issues/1

Answer (score 0):

I believe **asset_path_template** is not a method but a member in a hash

Try `config.action_controller["asset_path_template"]`